# How to get DropDownList SelectedValue to update Database

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I finally was able to get cascading drowdownlist working but I can not get the values to update the database table.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var strRowWid = "RowWid";
            var strDt = "Dt";
            var dateNow = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);

            //Date Dropdown
            ViewBag.DateWid = new SelectList(_context.TblDays.OrderByDescending(x => x.Dt).Where(n => n.Dt <= dateNow), strRowWid, strDt);

            //Ammo Type dropdown
            ViewBag.ammo = _context.VwAmmos.OrderBy(n => n.Caliber)
                .Select(n => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = n.RowWid.ToString(),
                    Text = n.WeaponType.ToString() + " " + n.Caliber.ToString() + " " + n.Brand.ToString() + " " + n.Style.ToString(),
                }).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TblUsed.DateWid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("DateWid", ViewBag.DateWid as SelectList, "--select date--", new { @class = "form-control form-select-sm form-select" })
                </div>
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TblUsed.AmmoWid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("AmmoWid",ViewBag.ammo, "--select Ammo--", new { @class = "form-control form-select-sm form-select" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TblUsed.StoreWid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("StoreWid",new SelectList(string.Empty,"StoreWid","StoreName"), new { @class = "form-control form-select-sm form-select" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TblUsed.QtyUsed" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TblUsed.QtyUsed" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TblUsed.QtyUsed" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Javascript for the cascade**

```
<script>
    $('#AmmoWid').change(function () {
           $('#StoreWid').empty();
    $.ajax({
           url: "@Url.Action("GetStore")",
           type: "Get",
            data: { id: $('#AmmoWid option:selected').val() },
           dataType:"json",
           success: function (result) {
               $.each(result, function (i,Store) {

                   $('#StoreWid').append('<option value="' + Store.value + '">' + Store.text+'</option>')
               })
           }
       })
       })
</script>
```

When I select the values from the dropdownlist and submit they do not update the database table.  It appears that they are not binded correctly.

I don't know what to try at this point.

When doing them like this I can get them to update but then I can't do the cascading.

```
<div class="form-group col-2">
                        <select asp-for="@Model.TblPurchase.AmmoWid" class="form-control form-select-sm form-select" asp-items="@Model.Ammo">
                            <option value="">Select Ammo</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TblPurchase.AmmoWid" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
```

**Create Post**

```
// POST: Useds/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("RowWid,DateWid,AmmoWid,QtyUsed,StoreWid")] TblUsed tblUsed)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(tblUsed);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(tblUsed);
    }
```

**TblUsed Model**

```
    namespace Ammo.Models;

public partial class TblUsed
{
    [Key]
    public int RowWid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TblDay")]
    [DisplayName("Date")]
    public int DateWid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TblAmmunition")]
    [DisplayName("Ammo")]
    public int AmmoWid { get; set; }

    public int QtyUsed { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TblStore")]
    [DisplayName("Store")]
    public int StoreWid { get; set; }
}
```

**VwAmmo Model**

```
    namespace Ammo.Models;

public partial class VwAmmo
{
    public int RowWid { get; set; }

    public string? WeaponType { get; set; }

    public string? Caliber { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Style { get; set; } = null!;

    public int? Grain { get; set; }

    public int? FtS { get; set; }

    public decimal? ShellSize { get; set; }

    public string? ShotType { get; set; }

    public string? Shot { get; set; }

    public decimal? GrainLoad { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please share the create post method with which model you have used to let us understand what has happened.

Comment: I updated the original post.  Sorry I missed that.

Comment: Please also share the TblUsed  model codes

Comment: TblUsed included and I also included VwAmmo since I use that as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you couldn't get the  tblUsed value is you used the wrong name for your attribute.

I suggest you could try to modify as below and then test. Besides, there is no need to put the bind attribute again.

View codes:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TblUsed.DateWid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("TblUsed.DateWid", ViewBag.DateWid , "--select date--", new { @class = "form-control form-select-sm form-select" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TblUsed.AmmoWid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("TblUsed.AmmoWid",ViewBag.ammo, "--select Ammo--", new { @class = "form-control form-select-sm form-select" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TblUsed.StoreWid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("TblUsed.StoreWid",new SelectList(string.Empty,"StoreWid","StoreName"), new { @class = "form-control form-select-sm form-select" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.TblUsed.QtyUsed" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.TblUsed.QtyUsed" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TblUsed.QtyUsed" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
<script>
    $('#TblUsed_AmmoWid').change(function () {
           $('#TblUsed_StoreWid').empty();
    $.ajax({
           url: "@Url.Action("GetStore")",
           type: "Get",
            data: { id: $('#TblUsed_AmmoWid option:selected').val() },
           dataType:"json",
           success: function (result) {
               $.each(result, function (i,Store) {

                   $('#TblUsed_StoreWid').append('<option value="' + Store.value + '">' + Store.text+'</option>')
               })
           }
       })
       })
</script>
}
```

[image]